# The best way to restore a database in SQL Server for critical databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to move a database from production environment into a new production environment.

The future environment has an old version of the current prod environment, I am migrating the old one now.

Is it better, more reliable if:

- I *DELETE* the database and then restore
- or should I just restore on top?

I know both are options, but I need to know which one gives the best result: best defined as leaves no room for error given this is a critical database, and mission-critical system.

I am not interested in differential database, I just want the current database to move in its entirety - cleanly and easily.

More info:

- this is a 25GB database
- I have a 2-hour window where I can take a backup of current system and put it on future system.
- And I've defined "best" above: easiest/simplest way while ensuring least amount of data corruption/loss.
- I do not need history/log in the new location, that is: I don't need to be able to go to an older time.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far? Your question is too broad: there is no such thing as **BEST** in every case. What is the size of your database? Allowed duration of offline? Speed of your network (or by what means you plan to transfer you database)?

Comment: @AlexYu Thank you. I added info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently asked a similar question. I disagree with the other answer: Detaching and attaching a database is not a good idea. First, you have to take it offline - second, you'll need to stop services as the other post pointed out. 
Backup and Restore is the safest method.

Option to detach the database using sp_detach_db and then attach it using CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH; or detach and attach using the GUI will actually detach the database from the source server.

> Many things can go wrong here, which is why we prefer backup and
>   restore. The backup process is online and since the source database
>   was never made un-available in the first place, you don't risk
>   destroying anything in case of mistakes, data corruption, or whatever
>   other things that can happen.

Have a look at this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101905/what-is-the-recommended-method-to-move-databases) that gives you everything you need.

On SQL Server the backup/restore process is straightforward and easy. If you have an existing database that choose to restore, it will replace it. If it doesn't exist, it will add it.

Comment: Note that OP wrote: **"I have a 2-hour window"**. Of course I agree that "On SQL Server the backup/restore process is straightforward and easy". But:  a) stopping service is easier and faster than BACKUP, b) zero-risk of data corruption, c) ALTER DATABASE .. FOR ATTACH - again is faster than RESTORE. So: having luxury of 2 hour window offline window - it is faster, more straightforward and less risky overall to go with so-called `cold backups` (database files)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to go [sp_detachdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-detach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - copy - [sp_attachdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-attach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) route.

Note that:

> The**@keepfulltextindexfile** parameter will be removed in a future version of SQL Server.

and this procedures are not compatible with Azure.

You wrote:

> I have a 2-hour window

So it will be better instead of `sp_detachdb` just stop SQLServer service - copy database files on new server and than use `sp_attach_db`/`CREATE DATABASE .. FOR ATTACH`

Read Microsoft documentation on this topic - [Move a Database Using Detach and Attach (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-a-database-using-detach-and-attach-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)